# Multiple actions were found that match the request Web API asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web API using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations) tutorial. I am running this API in `Postman`. GET, PUT and DELETE methods are working perfect but when I try to use the POST method it doesn't works and gives me an exception.

`{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nPostProduct on type ProductStoreApi.Controllers.ProductController\r\nPostProducts on type ProductStoreApi.Controllers.ProductController",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}`

**Update 1**

**Post Method**

```
public Product PostProduct(Product item)
    {
        item = repository.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PostProducts(Product item)
    {
        item = repository.Add(item);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);

        return response;
    }
```

**Note:-** In tutorial both the above methods have same name i.e. `PostProduct`. But when I try to write same names I always get an error.

**Routes**

```
 // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have searched many articles on that but couldn't find the perfect solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your controller code?

Comment: @MatJ updated the question

Comment: There's only one `PostProduct` in the tutorial - The 2nd is simply an update to the first.

Comment: Why do you have two methods? Use only the second. In the tutorial they are updating the first one using the second one implementation. It's normal to have an exception when you have two methods in one class with the same name and parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood the tutorial's `PostProduct` method:

> Next, we'll add a method to the ProductsController class to create a
>   new product. Here is a simple implementation of the method:
>
> ```
> // Not the final implementation!
> public Product PostProduct(Product item)
> {
>     item = repository.Add(item);
>     return item;
> }
> ```

Note that the code here explicitly warns you that this is **not the final implementation** of this method.

Later in the tutorial we have:

> ASP.NET Web API makes it easy to manipulate the HTTP response message.
>   Here is the **improved implementation**:
>
> ```
> public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product item)
> {
>     item = repository.Add(item);
>     var response = Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
>
>     string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
>     response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
>     return response;
> }
> ```

(my emphasis)

You are to *replace* the earlier `PostProduct` method with this improved implementation.

Comment: Yes i miss-understood the tutorial. :)